# json_encode(debug_backtrace()) returns "8 - Type is not supported"

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have PHP 7.3.27. I am trying to store a JSON-encoded version of debug_backtrace() in my database. However,

```
$bt = json_encode(debug_backtrace());
echo json_last_error() . ' - ' . json_last_error_msg();
```

returns:

```
8 - Type is not supported
```

If I print:

```
echo gettype(debug_backtrace());
```

it returns:

```
array
```

So I'm not sure why I'm getting that error. I've never encountered this issue with json_encode before on any array I've tried.

Comment: One of the values *in* the array is likely a resource, which can’t be serialised…

Comment: Good call! It looks like that's what it is. If I do print_r(debug_backtrace()) it looks like there is a resource. Now to figure out how to deal with that...